# How to prevent user from adding spaces in email input field?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I have a form which allows user to provide first and last name, email and department. The form is written in jsp and I want to modify the email input field in such a way that it wont allow user to add any spaces while entering email (i.e if they tried to add spaces courser will remain at the very beginning and also wont allow the spaces after entering email).

I was browsing Google to find the solution and found that its very simple with javaScript and jQuery but unfortunately I don't have much knowledge about it as most of the time I write code in java.

Here is the code snippet from my jsp form

```
<div class="formFields">
   <div class="formFieldsTop">
  <input type="hidden" name="CSRF_TOKEN" value="<%= pageBean.getCsrfToken()%>">
    <label id="firstNameTxt" class="boldText">First Name</label>
    <input class="requiredInput subUserFirstNameInput"  name="firstName"  type="textfield" size="30" maxlength="15" autocomplete="off" value="<%= NullSafe.subst(EcommerceFormat.escapeHtmlSafeString(delegateInfo.getFirstName()))%>">
    <label id="lastNameTxt" class="boldText">Last Name</label>
    <input class="requiredInput"  name="lastName" id="subUserLastNameInput" autocomplete="off" type="textfield" size="30" maxlength ="20" autocomplete="off" value="<%= NullSafe.subst(EcommerceFormat.escapeHtmlSafeString(delegateInfo.getLastName()))%>">
    <label id="emailTxt"><span class="boldText">Email Address*</span> (ex: email@yoursite.com)</label>
    <input class="requiredInput subUserEmailInput"  name="email" id="subUserEmailInput" type="textfield" size="30" autocomplete="off" maxlength="50" value="<%= NullSafe.subst(EcommerceFormat.escapeHtmlSafeString(delegateInfo.getEmailAddress()))%>">
    <label id="departmentTxt"><span class="bold">Department/Relationship</span> (optional)</label>
    <input name="department" type="textfield" size="30" autocomplete="off" maxlength="100" value="<%= NullSafe.subst(EcommerceFormat.escapeHtmlSafeString(delegateInfo.getDepartmentCode()))%>">
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to know if there is a way to prevent user from adding spaces in the email field by using jsp only or with combination of jsp, js and jQuery?

Answer (score 3):

You can try add type attribute to email input and required

```
<input type="email" required>
```

or add pattern attribute to email input

```
<input pattern="[a-z\._\d]{1,}@[a-z0-9]{2,}\.[a-z0-9]{2,}" required>
```

Comment: This won't prevent typing the `space` character, but submitting the form.

Comment: `document.querySelector("form").onsubmit = function (event) {
        var email = document.getElementById("inputemail").value;
        if (email.indexOf(" ") != -1){
            event.preventDefault();
            alert("Not allow space");
        }else{
            //go!
        }
    }`

Answer (score 1):

You basically want to have event listeners for when the form is submitted or when the user is typing in the field. I went with `keyup` since this isn't an actual form you have provided. If the input field of the e-mail has a `" "` then you would want to inform the user and decline the submitting of the form.

```
window.onload = function () {

  var emailField = document.getElementById("subUserEmailInput")

  emailField.addEventListener("keyup", function(evt){
    if (emailField.value.includes(" ") ) {
      //evt.preventDefault() you would want this if you were doing a submit to prevent it from happening
      emailField.style.border = "solid red 2px"
      alert("no spaces are allowed in your e-mail")
    } else {
      emailField.style.border = ""
    }
  })

}
```

https://codepen.io/dmc2015/pen/VodWJQ?editors=1111

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether this is the right solution that you're looking for, but this is one of the simple way to ensure the email is entered with the right format (without empty space).

In order to avoid user to enter any white space for email input field, you can change your `input` tag `type` attribute to the value `email`. With this type value, the input value will automatically validated to ensure it is a properly formatted e-mail address.

e.g. `<input type="email" name="emailaddress">`

However, this is only the front-end validation. You're still require to do some validation work when the data is submitted (To avoid user change the HTML code by using F12 code inspect on the browser).

Here is the code to verify whether a string is an email (USING JAVA):

```
String email ="xxxx@xxx.com"
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".+@.+\\.[a-z]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(email);
boolean matchFound = m.matches();
if (matchFound) {
    //execute code block, when input is email.
}
```

You may consider to put `.trim()` or `.replaceAll(" ", "")` for the submitted email string to ignore the submitted white space.